# Regex: Exclude from group, string that may or may not exist

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have this text

```
##### PRIORITY
- Priority 1
- Priority 2

##### ISSUE TYPE
<!--- comment -->
- Problem / Case
- Requirement
```

and I am trying to get **only** the options of each category, based on the title (priority, issue type).

My regular expression is like this:

```
(?:#####\s?issue type.*?)(?:<!---.*?-->)?(.*?)(?:#####|$)
```

I have separated three groups (title, comment, content).

If there is no comment block the regex works as it should, but if there is a comment block it gets captured by my third (content) group. How can I exclude the comment section, if it exists, from the third group?

I tried a negative lookahead like this:

```
(?:#####\s?issue type.*?)(?:<!---.*?-->)?(?!(<!---.*?-->).*?)(?:#####|$)
```

but doesn't seem to work.

[A link to pythex for help.](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%23%23%23%23%23%5Cs%3Fissue%20type.*%3F)(%3F%3A%3C!---.*%3F--%3E)%3F(.*%3F)(%3F%3A%23%23%23%23%23%7C%24)&test_string=%23%23%23%23%23%20PRIORITY%5Cr%5Cn%5Cr%5Cn-%20Priority%201%5Cr%5Cn-%20Priority%202%5Cr%5Cn%5Cr%5Cn%23%23%23%23%23%20ISSUE%20TYPE%5Cr%5Cn%3C!---%20comment%20--%3E%5Cr%5Cn%20-%20Problem%20%2F%20Case%5Cr%5Cn%20-%20Requirement&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=1&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with a lookahead:

```
(?:#####\s*issue type.*\s+)(?:<!---.*?-->\s+)?([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*(?:#####|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CmtKI7/2)

`(?=\s*(?:#####|$))` is a lookahead that assert we have `#####` or end of line ahead of current position. This helps you match multiple matches in the given input.

**Code:**

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:#####\s*issue type.*\s+)(?:<!---.*?-->\s+)?([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*(?:#####|$))', re.I)
>>> print(reg.findall(test_str))
['- Problem / Case\n- Requirement', '- Problem / Case\n- Requirement']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the improvements anubhava. It seems that the pythex website is giving completely different results and that had me also confused. So, the main problem was that I had used the dot (.) in my 3rd group which didn't match the newlines, and that's why I couldn't get any results, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. Also enabling DOTALL for whole regex is not required. Wherever needed we can use `[\s\S]` to match any character including new lines.